# Extract JSON data from column using Presto

Tags: mysql, sql, database, presto

I am using Presto and have a column_A with complex JSON data where **each cell** has an array that looks like this:

```
[{"value":"aaa", "items":["246","123"],...}, {"value":"bbb", "items":["357","123"],...}]
```

What I am trying to do is extract from each cell only the JSON object where "items" has code "357".

So ideally the output of the query would be new data in Column_B that has **one** JSON object (not an array) and looks like this:

```
{"value":"bbb", "items":["357","123"],...}
```

Note: for each cell, there is only one object with the code "357", however, "item" may have more than 1 code inside its array. As in the examples above.

So far I tried the below, but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(column_a, '$.(SELECT * from column_a where column_a::text LIKE '%357%')') AS column_extracted
FROM column_a
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I could try instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the newly introduced [JSON path](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json-path-language) functions in Trino (formerly known as Presto SQL) for this:

```sql
WITH t(data) AS (
    VALUES '[{"value":"aaa", "items":["246","123"]}, {"value":"bbb", "items":["357","123"]}]'
)

SELECT json_query(t.data, 'strict $[*]?(@.items[*] == "357")')
FROM t
```

which produces:

```
                 _col0
---------------------------------------
 {"value":"bbb","items":["357","123"]}
(1 row)
```

If you look at `$[*]?(@.items[*] == "357")`, it says "find all the elements of the top-level array that match the condition `@.items[*] == "357"`", which, in turn, checks whether any of the elements in the `items` array has a value of `357`.